# Save data from View Results in Table to file and then add it to jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I'm using Jenkins job to run jmeter test plan. In my jmeter test plan I have "Results in Table" listener there is an option to save listener output to file and I'm using that option.
But I can't specify correct path to see that output in Jenkins job's workspace.

How should I configure Jenkins job, or what path should I specify in jmeter listener to see my saved file in Jenkins job's workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jenkins has any suitable plugin to display [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener data.

There is [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which can be used for JMeter test results visualization, check out [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for details.

Comment: I don't need to display (visualise) View Results in Table. All I need is to be able to save results to file and add this file to Jenkins job workspace. May be you know how to do that?!?

Comment: Post-build Actions -> Archive the artifacts -> jtl file name

Comment: to  use this, my file should be already in the workspace... And my main problem and purpose of the question is -"How to save file to workspace"??????????????????????/

Comment: Given you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) via Jenkins build step like `jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l result.jtl` you should be able to use `result.jtl` in the "Files to archive" input, after that you will be able to see the `result.jtl` in your build artifacts !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!